# Javadb error: “TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated”

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, timestamp

I am using Javadb in Netbeans.

One month before I created a program that stores values in the database (javadb) that comes along with Netbeans.

Note that `uname`, `paname`, `hostid` are all corrrect.

Now I try to connect and run but it is giving the following error:

> TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option

So I suppose I should enable `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`, but I don't know how. Where do I find it in Netbeans? I am using Javadb that comes along with Netbeans 7.6.

What exactly is going on? I am storing  a string from a text field in the database. Where does the default timestamp comes into the picture? Also one of the [documents from pretty related Mysql 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) states that the default timestamp is 00-00-00 00:00:00. Ok, but how did this deprecate over a one month period, what did it deprecate to?